# How to trim spaces and new lines from start and end and replace multiple new lines and wide spaces with single in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, trim

[image: Sample Comment]

Hello Mates ... i am having an issue which may be very simple for you but for me its a quite mess ... may be it looks like a common issue but i have not found yet any case that is similar as mine ... i have a site on which users can add comments to the post ... now what i want is that when user puts more than one space it should be converted to a single space and same should be done with multiple new lines ... beside this i also want to trim out wide spaces and new lines from beginning and end of the string ... check out the link (image) for the screen shot of sample input

Here is my code :

```
 $(document).on('keydown','.addComment',function(e){
    var id = $(this).attr('id').match(/\d+/);
    var p_id = Number(id);
    var comment_box = '#comment_box_'+id;
    var content = $(comment_box).html();
    content = content.replace(/\n/g, '<br>'); //replacing new line with <br>
    if (e.which === 13 && e.shiftKey !== true) {

        if (content.length > 0  ) {

            $.ajax({

                type : 'POST',
                url  : 'update.php',
                data: ({
                    content: content,
                    id: p_id,
                    act: "add_cmnt"
                }),
                success : function()
                {
                    update_ca("comment_area_"+id, true);
                }
            }); //End of Ajax
        }
        return false;
        }
        });
```

here is code for html input :

```
<p contenteditable="true" class=" addComment" id="comment_box_***"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code:

```
content = content.replace(/\n+/gm, '\n').replace(/\u0020+/gm, ' ').replace(/\n/g, '<br>');
```

Best regards.